# Wordpress no muestra pluggins

Tags: wordpress

estaba haciendo unas configuraciones en `wordpress` pero se cayó el servidor y cuando se restableció no esta el `pluggin`, solo salió un mensaje de que `wordepress` desactivó por error en cabecera.

volví a subir el plugin, este se sube normal, se instala, pero no sale en la lista de plugin, ya lo he vuelto a subir 4 veces pero no sale en la lista de plugin.

Comment: ¿Estás en local o en remoto? ¿Seguro que el plugin está bien programado (funcionaba antes)? ¿Cómo lo estás *subiendo*?

Comment: Otra cosa que yo probaría sería acceder por ftp (o cualquier sistema de acceso) y eliminar la carpeta del plugin (normalmente en la ruta wp-content->Plugins) y volverlo a instalar desde cero.